# Trying to understand exif.encode_unicode

Tags: php, utf-8, exif

Occasionally I get PHP errors from my site's users uploading photos, and the EXIF data not being valid UTF-8 when I subsequently try to `json_encode` it. The specific error I get is:

```
E_WARNING: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument
```

That's generated by the final line of the code below.

```
ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');
$exif_data = exif_read_data($uploader_target_dir . $_POST['uploader_' . $i . '_tmpname']);
$when_photo_taken = isset($exif_data['DateTime']) ? (int)strtotime($exif_data['DateTime']) : 0;
$exif_data = (json_encode($exif_data));
```

As you can see, I'm setting the `exif.encode_unicode` option to `UTF-8`, although I'm not 100% sure of what this does (the sentence "exif.encode_unicode defines the characterset UNICODE user comments are handled" in the manual seems pretty ambiguous/confusing to me), but either way it hasn't fixed the problem.

Does anyone know exactly what this configuration option does? Or what is causing my `E_WARNING`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that that config tells the exif code which character set to convert *to* when it's converting the text that is stored in the image.

The issue will be that some of the text read from the exif data will either claim to be in UTF-8 format but actually has some invalid bytes, or is in some other way garbled.

If you want to investigate the cause of the issue, which may be worth reporting as a bug if it affects lots of images, you can get the raw bytes from the text, and should be able to see what exactly is causing the error by emitting the raw bytes:

```
foreach ($exif_data as $key => $value) {

    $resultInHex = unpack('H*', $value);
    $resultInHex = $resultInHex[1];
    $resultSeparated = implode(', ', str_split($resultInHex, 2)); //byte safe

    var_dump($resultSeparated);
}
```

If you don't care and just want to cleanse your data so that it stops throwing errors, you can just remove all non-valid UTF8 characters from your users data - which you probably should be anyway.

```
function removeInvalidChars ($text) {
    $regex = '/( [\x00-\x7F] | [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] | [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} | [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3} ) | ./x';
    return preg_replace($regex, '$1', $text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. Using the above snippets I was able to determine that the issues were caused by trying to JSON encode the `MakerNote` EXIF tag, which on further investigation is not going to work in the majority of cases, as the content is in a proprietary binary format.